# spark 2.2 fails to handle map columns in aggregation expression

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, apache-spark-sql, distinct

How can I `GROUP BY` or use  `DISTINCT` an a complex type column with a map?:

```
case class Foo(id:Int, stuff:Map[String, Int])
  val xx = Seq(Foo(1, Map("first" -> 1, "second"->2)), Foo(1, Map("first" -> 1, "second"->2)), Foo(3, Map("fourth" -> 4, "fifth"->5))).toDF
  xx.distinct.show
  xx.groupBy("id", "stuff").count.show
```

the error is

```
expression `stuff` cannot be used as a grouping expression because its data type map<string,int> is not an orderable data type
```

It seems to be related to https://mapr.com/support/s/article/Spark-SQL-queries-on-Map-column-fails-with-exception-Cannot-have-map-type-columns-in-DataFrame?

Maybe fixed in spark 2.4?

However, I am currently restricted to 2.2. Is there a solution for 2.2?

Could it instead be converted to json? I would need to have a struct with different fields per record ([spark dynamically create struct/json per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571732/spark-dynamically-create-struct-json-per-group)).

## edit

- manually serializing to JSON is a workaround (but rather clumsy)
- instead of using a map type column I can also use an array of custom case classes i.e. `Seq[Foo]; case class Foo(column:String, column_value:String, value:String)`. This allows `DISTINCT` to work, but the format seems to be rather unintuitive for any 3rd party